# How to download or list all files on a website directory

Tags: html, httpserver

I have a pdf link like www.xxx.org/content/a.pdf, and I know that there are many pdf files in www.xxx.org/content/ directory but I don't have the filename list. And When I access www.xxx.org/content/ using browser, it will redirect to www.xxx.org/home.html.

I tried to use wget like "wget -c -r -np -nd --accept=pdf -U NoSuchBrowser/1.0 www.xxx.org/content", but it returns nothing.

So does any know how to download or list all the files in www.xxx.org/content/ directory?

Comment: If the web server does not voluntarily divulge a list of *valid URLs*, there's no way you can make it do so.

Comment: `www.xxx.org/content/` is not a directory. It's a URL. There is zero guarantee that this URL represents a file system directory. In fact, there's zero guarantee that `www.xxx.org/content/a.pdf` links to some file on a file system.

Answer (score 0):

If the site www.xxx.org blocks the listing of files in HTACCESS, you can't do it.

Comment: "HTACCESS" is very specific to a certain web server… More generally speaking: *if the web server does not offer a URL which lists all available URLs ("files")…*

Answer (score 0):

Try to use File Transfer Protocol with FTP path you can download and access all the files from the server. Get the absolute path of of the same URL "www.xxx.org/content/" and create a small utility of ftp server and get the work done.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING**: **This may be illegal without permission from the website owner.**  Get permission from the web site first before using a tool like this on a web site.  This can create a Denial of Service (DoS) on a web site if not properly configured (or if not able to handle your requests).  It can also cost the web site owner money if they have to pay for bandwidth.

You can use tools like dirb or dirbuster to search a web site for folders/files using a wordlist.  You can get a wordlist file by searching for a "dictionary file" online.

http://dirb.sourceforge.net/
https://sectools.org/tool/dirbuster/